# Parsing JSON_Decoded array in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I am passing data to an ajax call that has been 'json_stringified'. I am able to pass the data to PHP, however when trying to access the items within the passed array, I receive the following error:

'Trying to get property of non-object'

I've tried several things, but I am stuck. Can someone please assist? My code is below:

js:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/VibeSetter/services/getlocationsFavs.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "POST",               
        data: {favs: JSON.stringify(localStorage.getArray("myFavs"))},
        success: function(data, status)
        {
            $.each(data, function(i,item)
            { 
                //pass to function to fill array
                      populateLocationsArray(i+1, item.idlocations,item.name,item.longitude, item.latitude);

            });
        },

         error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            console.log(arguments);
        //  alert('HTTP Error: '+errorThrown+' | Error     Message:'+textStatus);

        }
    });
```

}

console.log(localStorage.getArray("myFavs")) returns:

{locations: 1},{locations: 0},{locations: 4293315}

php:

```
<?php
  header('Content-type: application/json');

  include 'config.php';
  $data = json_decode($_POST['favs']);
  var_dump($data);

  foreach($data as $d)
  {
      print $d->locations;
  }

  ?>
```

which returns the following in chrome developer tools pane:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "{locations: 1}"
  [1]=>
  string(14) "{locations: 0}"
  [2]=>
  string(20) "{locations: 4293315}"
  }
```

**Notice**:  Trying to get property of non-object in **C:\xampp\htdocs\VibeSetter\services\getlocationsFavs.php** on line **10**

**Notice**:  Trying to get property of non-object in **C:\xampp\htdocs\VibeSetter\services\getlocationsFavs.php** on line **10**

**Notice**:  Trying to get property of non-object in **C:\xampp\htdocs\VibeSetter\services\getlocationsFavs.php** on line **10**

Can someone please tell me how to access each element of this array? The idea is to parse each 'location' value and concatenate the locations in a query further in the code as specific values in a query search.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you able to post your full array?

Comment: check $_POST['favs'] if it is ["{locations: 1}","{locations: 0}","{locations: 4293315}"]

Comment: var_dump($_POST['favs']); returns string(58) "["{locations: 1}","{locations: 0}","{locations: 4293315}"]"

Answer (score 0):

Considering `$_POST['favs']` have value as `'[{"locations": "1"},{"locations": "0"},{"locations": "4293315"}]';`

Then,

```
$array = json_decode($_POST['favs'],TRUE);
foreach($array as $d)
{
    print $d['locations'];
}
```

When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

**[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)**

Comment: I thought the same thing and tried that previously. Unfortunately, all that does is return this error:                                             <br />

<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'locations' in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\VibeSetter\services\getlocationsFavs.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br />
{